# Select all checkbox in Tcl/Tk tablelist header

Tags: checkbox, tcl, tk-toolkit

How to implement a checkbox inside the header of tcl/tk [Tablelist](http://www.nemethi.de/tablelist/tablelist.html) for implementing a select all functionality. I have not been able to find any resource . Is it possible in any method? Please guide.

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://www.nemethi.de/tablelist/tablelist.html) tablelist widget? Are you sure that that's what your users would expect? (They mostly expect click on header to mean “sort by that column”…)

Comment: I was refering to a checkbutton inside Header, for example :  http://www.ssw.com.au/SSW/standards/rules/Images/SelectAllCheckBox_Web.jpg

Comment: I have previously thought of using -labelcommand option but later discarded the idea for the same reason you mentioned in earlier comment.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to answer the main question. 
"Do you mean this tablelist widget?" -yes I am using this tablelist widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bypassed the problem as I have not found any direct method to add a widget in tablelist header.
i have used two 16x16 png images (one of a unchecked box [image: Unchecked] ; another checked box [image: Checked] ) as the -labelimage which was toggled with the labelcommand.

In this way user have a clue of the action of clicking that box ( actually the whole header ).
[image]

Sample code:(not optimized)

```
package require Tk
package require tablelist
package require Img

namespace eval ::test {
    variable toggleState 0
}
proc onClick {tbl col} {
if {$::test::toggleState==0} {
    .tbl columnconfigure 0 -labelimage .image.uncheckedbox
    ## ENTER YOUR CODE HERE TO DESELECT ALL CHECKBOX IN CELL WINDOW OF 0th COLUMN.
    set ::test::toggleState 1
} else {
    .tbl columnconfigure 0 -labelimage .image.checkedbox
    ## ENTER YOUR CODE HERE TO SELECT ALL CHECKBOX IN CELL WINDOW OF 0th COLUMN.
    set ::test::toggleState 0
}

}

tablelist::tablelist .tbl -columntitles {col1 col2 col3} -height 10 -width 100 -stretch all -stripebackground #e0e8f0
grid .tbl -padx 5 -pady 5 -sticky news

    image create photo .image.checkedbox -file {E:\path\checked.png}
    image create photo .image.uncheckedbox -file {E:\path\unchecked.png}

.tbl columnconfigure 0 -labelimage .image.uncheckedbox -labelcommand onClick
```